# Hibernate design for many to one mapping

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, orm

Say there is **one** flower shop which has *fixed* types of bouquets

```
class FlowerShop{
 Bouquet[] bouquets;
 }
```

Bouquet has *few* type of flowers

```
 class Bouquet{
  int bouquetId;
  List<Flower> flowers;
   }
```

Flower has some *fixed* properties

```
class Flower{
  String name;
  ColorEnum color;
  int flowerId;
  int bouquetId;
   ... //other properties
  }
```

What would be a suitable table design to achieve this?

**Option 1**: Since the class Bouquet has only bouquetId then have only one table

```
 Flowers {flowerId,bouquetId,name,color,etc,etc..}
```

Here i will have to iterate over the flower objects and use a map `bouquetId->List<Flower>`
After this i need to construct Bouquet objects which each bouquetId
and then construct the FlowerShop with array of bouquet objects

**Option 2:**

```
Flowers    {flowerId,name,color,etc,etc} 
Bouquets   {bouquetId,flowerId} 
FlowerShop {bouquetId}
```

I am not really sure about the 3rd table.There is only one flower shop.
I think i will need to select all bouquet objects and programmatically creating FlowerShop object from bouquets.Can I get hibernate to create the FlowerShop object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create only Flower table.

```
Flowers {flowerId,BouquetEnum_name,name,color,etc,etc}
```

For Bouquets, you'll create an Enum instead of a table. So when you want to get all the flowers of a bouquet, you will put the Enum corresponding to certain bouquet on the WHERE clause of flowers query. Is there only one flower shop? So you will create it programmatically and the object will be composed by lists of flowers where each list represents one kind of bouquet (the kinds of bouquet will be on the BouquetEnum).

I Guess it seems like your Option 1.